# Forecast function to predict future portfolio worth?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to fill in D6 to D9 to populate the predicted amount based on the data in A and B in the image below?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
=TREND(B1:B8,$A$1:$A8,$D$9:$D11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FORECAST(C1:C8, B1:B8, A1:A8))
```

[image]